# Python Pyparsing Located vs locatedExpr

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyparsing

I am changing a few pyparsing patterns from pyparsing version 2 to pyparsing version 3.

The contents of the sample file I use for parsing

```
this is a sample page to test parsing
line 0001 line 1
line 0002 line 2
```

the pattern used to create parser

```
p.Literal('line ') + p.Regex(r'(?P<abc>\d+)') + p.SkipTo(p.LineEnd().suppress())
```

When I using the locatedExpr from version2 I get the following output

```
{'locn_start': 55, 'abc': '0002', 'value': ['line ', '0002', ' line 2'], 'locn_end': 71}
```

when I use Located from version 3 I get the following output for the same pattern

```
{'locn_start': 55, 'value': {'abc': '0002'}, 'locn_end': 71}
```

However if I remove the named capturing group from the pattern  like below example

```
[p.Literal('line ') + p.Regex(r'\d+')] + p.SkipTo(p.LineEnd().suppress())
```

I get the same output as locatedExpr

```
{'locn_start': 55, 'value': ['line ', '0002', ' line 2'], 'locn_end': 71}
```

However I like to group the information in my parsing and I was wondering if anybody know the difference between Located and locatedExpr

In all the above cases I am using `parse_with_tabs`

Comment: Is this pyparsing 3.0.9?

Comment: Yes this is pyparsing 3.0.9

Comment: What is the purpose of the []'s in `[p.Literal('line ') + p.Regex(r'\d+')] + p.SkipTo(p.LineEnd().suppress())`?

Comment: `locatedExpr` is deprecated in favor of `Located`, introduced in 3.0.0.

Comment: Why did you edit the question so severely? Don't make it non understandable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be using `as_dict()` to view the contents of the parsed results. `as_dict()` does not display unnamed elements in the results. Please use the `dump()` method instead. Pyparsing's `run_tests` method uses `dump()` to display the parsed results:

```py
import pyparsing as p

tests = """
    line 0002 line 2
"""

parser = p.Literal('line ') + p.Regex(r'(?P<abc>\d+)') + p.SkipTo(p.LineEnd().suppress())
p.Located(parser).run_tests(tests)
p.locatedExpr(parser).run_tests(tests)

parser = p.Literal('line ') + p.Regex(r'\d+') + p.SkipTo(p.LineEnd().suppress())
p.Located(parser).run_tests(tests)
p.locatedExpr(parser).run_tests(tests)
```

prints

```
line 0002 line 2
[0, ['line ', '0002', 'line 2'], 16]
- locn_end: 16
- locn_start: 0
- value: ['line ', '0002', 'line 2']
  - abc: '0002'
[0]:
  0
[1]:
  ['line ', '0002', 'line 2']
  - abc: '0002'
[2]:
  16

line 0002 line 2
[[0, 'line ', '0002', 'line 2', 16]]
[0]:
  [0, 'line ', '0002', 'line 2', 16]
  - abc: '0002'
  - locn_end: 16
  - locn_start: 0
  - value: ['line ', '0002', 'line 2']

line 0002 line 2
[0, ['line ', '0002', 'line 2'], 16]
- locn_end: 16
- locn_start: 0
- value: ['line ', '0002', 'line 2']
[0]:
  0
[1]:
  ['line ', '0002', 'line 2']
[2]:
  16

line 0002 line 2
[[0, 'line ', '0002', 'line 2', 16]]
[0]:
  [0, 'line ', '0002', 'line 2', 16]
  - locn_end: 16
  - locn_start: 0
  - value: ['line ', '0002', 'line 2']
```

The new `Located` class is more consistent in how it reports the parsed value, whether it does or does not contain any named items or regex groups.